# How to generate unique but consistent N-bit hash (less than 64 bit) for strings?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, hash, checksum

I want following mechanism:

```
int64_t MyHash (const std::string& value);
```

- Give any `std::string` (usually 100 bytes) as an input
- The function outputs a 64-bit integer value
- However the maximum value represented by that integer should be in the range of `-2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>53</sup>-1`

I tried using `std::hash()`; The problem with that is: It's different on every platform. Not only that, with every run it differs.

Currently, using `Qt`'s `QCryptographicHash` I am getting an `SHA256` checksum and that I am truncating to 64-bit. Even in this truncation, also the collision possibility will increase.
Anyhow, my goal is to get that value within 54 bits. One obvious solution is to divide that number by 2048.

**Question**: Is there any better solution to get a hash of 54-bit?
Javascript solution is also fine.

**Purpose**: This value is passed to Javascript. Now it's datatype `number` can hold a 64-bit double, which is of 54 bits.

Comment: The pigeonhole principle says that you simply cannot has 256^100 different strings to 2^54 unique hashes. In fact, you can't even hash 256^7 different strings to 2^54 unique hashes. The best you can hope for is evenly distributed, i.e. you have 2^746 collisions for each hash.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a 54 bit hash, you're likely to trade quality for speed. In SHA256, the bottom 54 bits will give as reliable a hash as it's reasonably possible to get, at the cost of not the best performance.

Other possibilities are a 64 bit CRC, which can very easily be found with a quick google search. That's likely to be faster, and still probably fine for any reasonable use case.

As for truncation to the [-2<sup>53</sup> .. 2<sup>53</sup> - 1] range, I'd just use `&` with a suitable bitmask, and then subtract 2<sup>53</sup>.

2<sup>53</sup> is 0x20000000000000, so it would just be:

crc = crc - 0x20000000000000LL;

As for the 64 bit CRC itself, the following code is taken directly from http://andrewl.dreamhosters.com/filedump/crc64.cpp which is a downloadable .cpp file.  The original is written using Windows data types, I've converted here to normal `stdint.h` types.

```
unit64_t const poly = 0xC96C5795D7870F42ULL;
uint64_t table[256];

void generate_table()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        uint64_t crc = i;

        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            if(crc & 1)
            {
                crc >>= 1;
                crc ^= poly;
            }
            else
            {
                crc >>= 1;
            }
        }
        table[i] = crc;
    }
}
```

You'll want to call `generate_table()` exactly once at program startup.  Either that, or run it in a small harness which just prints out the results, and directly initialize the table using those values.

To actually evaluate the crc, pass the sequence of bytes and the length to this:

```
uint64_t calculate_crc(uint8_t *stream, size_t n)
{
    uint64_t crc = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        uint8_t index = stream[i] ^ crc;
        uint64_t lookup = table[index];

        crc >>= 8;
        crc ^= lookup;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Depending on how curious you are, it may be worth taking a look at the linked source, it has extensive comments that explain what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. Can you put any known algo of CRC? Also what do you mean by substraction of 2^53? An equation will be helpful.

Comment: @iammilind: You first produce a value in the range [0...2^52^-1], and then subtract 2^53 to get a possible range [-2^53, 2^53-1]